# Merge several lists together and make them suggestions for search bar

Tags: javascript

I want to merge several lists together and then take them as suggestions for an input field.
I have a solution for one list but I cant get it to work with several lists.
I get a nodelist and convert it into an array of HTMLUList elements. I think I need one big HTMLUlist ?!
Thanks for the help I hope you understand my problem.

```
 let filter = this.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
  

  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  // This works for one list "myUL"
  //-------------------------------------------------
  //This does not work 
  
  let filter = this.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.querySelectorAll (" #myUL , #myUL2 , #myUL3, #myUL4 , #myUL5 , #myUL6 ");
  var inputList = Array.prototype.slice.call(ul);
  li = inputList.getElementsByTagName('li');
```

Comment: um, can u give an example of the inputs and expected outputs.. cuz i don't understand ur explaination fully

Comment: example, what do you mean by "merge lists" and for "suggestions" u can change the `placeholder` aspect of the html element so it would show a shadow of whatever

Comment: Ehm in the second example I have a list of HTMLULists thats why it throws the error "Uncaught TypeError: inputList.getElementsByTagName is not a function". I need to make one big HTMLUlist out of the array ?! How would I achieve this ?

Comment: It works if I write it like this "li = inputList[0].getElementsByTagName('li'); " But then again it only takes one of the 6 lists.

Comment: querySelectorAll gives me one big HTML collection I think. But if I got it right I need one big HTMUlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your approach doesn't seem very effective for me, you can achieve by looping through ul elements:

```js
let filter = this.value.toUpperCase();
let uls = document.querySelectorAll('#myUL, #myUL2 ,#myUL3, #myUL4, #myUL5, #myUL6');
uls.forEach(ul => {
   let li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li'); 
   // continue as above
})
```

Comment: Thank you ! I already thought I have to loop it somehow. What do you think would be more effective though ?